# Getting error virtualbox-guest-modules: requires linux<4.0 on antergos while doing system upgrade

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualbox

I am running Antergos Linux 64 bit on virtual box. when I try to do full system upgrade I get a error:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: virtualbox-guest-modules: requires linux<4.0
```

I am using Ubuntu as my host OS and it's kernel version is 3.13.0-49-generic and in Antergos is using 3.19.3-3-ARCH. I guess both are less than linux 4.0.

Comment: Maybe Antergos uses a different package name to provide the kernel. What is the output of `pacman -Q linux` and `pacman -Qo /boot/vmlinuz-linux`?

Comment: output is  linux 3.19.3-3

Comment: Do you have the `testing` repo enabled? It seems 4.0 is being released there, but if you do, you should also be getting the `testing` version of virtualbox-guest-modules...

Comment: Yes, I do have testing repo enabled

Answer (score 0):

You cannot both

- upgrade `linux` to version 4.0+ **and**
- have a package which depends on a version of linux less than 4.0

This is a dependency conflict. One workaround is to add the `linux` package to `IgnorePkg` on `/etc/pacman.conf`, but this action is not usually recommended by the Arch developers, since [partial upgrades are unsupported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported).

Note: antergos is based on Arch.